# Should tags [kubernetes-apiserver] and [kube-apiserver] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

It's not really a question, of course they should!

Tags [kubernetes-apiserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-apiserver) and [kube-apiserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kube-apiserver) clearly and unambiguously refer to the same thing. Whether that thing's significant enough to warrant tagging is a different issue, but certainly anything that's tagged with one is desired by search results for the other.